# SharePoint REST (and CSOM) fails for External Users

Tags: rest, sharepoint, csom

I am retrieving list items using REST and all works just fine for internal users - I am using Office 365 and it works fine for both AD accounts that are synched and federated (with ADFS), as well as the accounts @onmicrosoft.com.

However, the same code fails with external users (I tested with both Organizational accounts and Microsoft account) with the same error:
"A list, survey, discussion board, or document library with the specified title already exists in this Web site.  Please choose another title."

This error obviously does not make any sense, since I am just retrieving list items.

I rewrote the whole thing using CSOM instead of REST, with the exact same result.

I can't find it again, but I remember reading somewhere that External Users were treated as Anonymous users when using client side code. In Office 365, you can't provide access to anonymous users, so if this is true, I wonder what I can do?

any ideas?
Pierre

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add external users (users who don’t have any O365 licence to access your tenant/O365) to SharePoint online and authorize Sharing with External users.

You can check the detailes step here:

http://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/08/23/office-365-sharepoint-online-managing-external-users/

After this also check if they are able to browse that list there credentials.

Comment: Yes, the account(s) I use to test access for external users have been authorized. I have no problem to navigate the document library using this account using the SharePoint UI.